# NSArray unrecognized selector sent to instance on Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new to Objective-C And here I have a Json that I've stored into a NSArray. And I am trying to get the *English, Dutch, Portuguese*

```
{
English =     (
One,
Two,
Three

);
Dutch =     (
Een
);

Portuguese =     (
Um,
Dois
}
```

And here's what I've done:

```
languageArray = result;

for (i = [languageArray count] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    NSString *languageTitle = [languageArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"languageTitle %@", languageTitle);
}
```

And I have this error *-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c68e53610* but my languageArray count is 3. I don't know why I can't get the objectAtIndex:i I've tried to use objectAtIndex:0 but still the same result

Comment: The top level is a dictionary, not an array. In other words, `result` is a dictionary.

Comment: I see. Can I get the value of the 'keys'? How?

Comment: See the documentation for `NSDictionary`.

Comment: `NSDictionary` has _keys_ not _indices_; therefore there is no such selector which you try to invoke and the raised exception is pretty much a clear message about it. `–objectForKey:` is your buddy here.

Comment: But if I use objectForKey:"@English" it would return One,Two,Three. I need to get English

Comment: then grabbed `allKeys` (assorted array!) property and you can use the `–objectAtIndex:` on that array, but as long as it is an assorted array, the first item at index `0` may not be the _English_ at every occasion or ever.

Comment: Got it. But how can I add One,Two,Three to the key English?

Comment: the `One`, `Two`, `Three` are already values in the array under key `English`, you don't need to add them again; or I might not get your issue here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
NSArray*languages = [result allKeys];
```

for getting values for languages you have to do this

```
  NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i=0 ; i<languages.count ; i++){
            [mutableArray addObject:[result valueForKey:[languages objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]]];
        }
```

So finally you have mutable array which contains values for every language as array;

You can get values for english with respect to index of language.

For example you can get values for `Dutch` as

```
NSArray *dutchValues = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Then how can I add One,Two,Three to the key English? And so on